# Yahoo Finance API with Json/Jquery isn't working well?

Tags: jquery, json, search, yahoo, finance

I am learning how to parse json and query and was looking at other questions: I saw that someone was using the below URL to get ticker symbols and values. I also wanted to get the actual stock value, but I will figure that out later.

My jquery code is supposed to parse the JSON format that it gives but I am new at this and it doesn't seem to be working the way I understand it to work. Sorry if this is a bit of a "nooby" question.

```
http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yahoo&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

It returns this, I reformatted it and validated it to make it readable and to check it:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({
   "ResultSet":{
      "Query":"google",
      "Result":[
         {
            "symbol":"GOOG",
            "name":"Google Inc.",
            "exch":"NMS",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"NASDAQ",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GOOG.MX",
            "name":"Google Inc.",
            "exch":"MEX",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Mexico",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.DE",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"GER",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"XETRA",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.SG",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"STU",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Stuttgart",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.HA",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"HAN",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Hanover",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.MU",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"MUN",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Munich",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.F",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"FRA",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Frankfurt",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GOOG11BF.SA",
            "name":"GOOGLE      -DRN     MB",
            "exch":"SAO",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Sao Paolo",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GOOF.EX",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"EUX",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"EUREX Futures and Options Exchange ",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GGQ1.HM",
            "name":"GOOGLE-A",
            "exch":"HAM",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Hamburg",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         }
      ]
   }
})
```

this is the part of my code to parse that url exactly:

```
function(data) {
                  $("#quotes").empty();
                  $.each(data.query.search, function(i, Result){
                    $("#quotes").append("<div>" + ResultSet.Result.symbol + "</a><br>" + ResultSet.Result.name + "<br><br></div>");
                  });
                });
```

Comment: what is `query.search`, data is the JSON Object, `query` is listed as `Query` and is case sensitive, so that won't work, and `search` is not a `key` with your `json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're trying to achieve with the code above, and the JSON structure, you would like to iterate over each `Result` and retrieve the properties of that object, then output them as a div, here you go:

```
$.each(data.ResultSet.Result, function(i, Result){  
  $("#quotes").append("<div>Symbol: "+Result.symbol+", Name: "+Result.name+" <br/><br/></div>");
});
```

[Here is the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Qra/)